# MX Linux, Xfce: ibus doesn't work

Tags: xfce, input-method, mx-linux, ibus

I installed ibus, ibus-gtk, ibus-gtk3.
I also installed ibus-unikey and ibus-bamboo, which are packages required for typing in Vietnamese.
I added the following lines in ~/.bashrc

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

Set ibus daemon to automatically run at startup as `ibus-daemon --xim`
I also ran im-config, choosing ibus option at user configuration.
And I still cannot type Vietnamese characters. Am I missing any steps? Or am I not providing enough information? Helps are appreciated.

Comment: I installed MX Linux just for fun and now I deeply doubt why I even did that... I absolutely had much fewer issues like this when I was using Ubuntu or CentOS. Also, same is happening to me I am using Mate desktop, trying to add Chinese input.

Comment: Well after I complained here yesterday, I found this: https://mxlinux.org/wiki/other/chinese-simplified-input/. Followed it, and also installed `ibus-pinyin`, and then rebooted, I now have Pinyin input for Chinese. Not sure how Vietnamese input works though. For Chinese, I need something called "input method", which is that "ibus-pinyin" I installed.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it in MX Linux 23. I installed ibus-gtk, ibus-gtk3 ibus-gtk4.
"sudo apt install ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 ibus-gtk4"